# In PostgreSQL procedure need to update some columns by adding them or subtracting same calculated value, but do the calculation once for row

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-update

HERE some code that I tried on PostgreSQL 14.2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_table_data(IN zipCode integer, IN studyYears integer, IN calculationData json[])
    language plpgsql
AS
$$
    DECLARE additional_progress DOUBLE PRECISION
BEGIN
    UPDATE some_table
    SET
        additional_progress = someCalculationFunction(calculationData, some_table.formula),
        current_progress = progress + additional_progress,
        total_progress = total_points + additional_progress,
        progress_left = progress_left - additional_progress
    WHERE zip_code = zipCode AND study_years = studyYears
    COMMIT;
END;
$$;
```

As a result I want to make ***someCalculationFunction*** to work *only once for each row*, because  I don't need it called for each column that will be updated separately.

Comment: The function **will** only be called once per row. What makes you think it's called per column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,
This code part is not working, I mean that it works for me if I call it for every column like:
current_progress = progress + someCalculationFunction(calculationData, some_table.formula),
total_progress = total_points + someCalculationFunction(calculationData, some_table.formula),
progress_left = progress_left - someCalculationFunction(calculationData, some_table.formula)

Comment: Your code and your comment are very different, why do you think it should behave the same? And could you please share to code for that function as well?

Comment: @FrankHeikens,
My code is not working, if it worked, then there would be no need to write a question. In the comment I tried to explain what I need to get and why. Calculation function is a some created function, which code working, its inner structure unimportant for this question, but I can say that it returns (double precision) type value. And there is not type mismatch with other fields.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution for this after many tries:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_table_data(IN zipCode integer, IN studyYears integer, IN calculationData json[])
        language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE some_table AS s
    SET
        current_progress = progress + mod_s.additional_progress,
        total_progress = total_points + mod_s.additional_progress,
        progress_left = progress_left - mod_s.additional_progress
            FROM ( SELECT id, someCalculationFunction(calculationData, formula) AS additional_progress FROM some_table) mod_s
    WHERE mod_s.additional_progress > 0 AND s.id = mod_s.id;
    COMMIT;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).